# scrollLeft within a scrollable div which has overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a custom content scroller. Basically the idea is that upon a button click the contents of the container is scrolled horizontally to an element within the container that has a class of `page`. The element that has class `page` gets changed on each click, so there is always a new element to scroll to.

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollLeft: $(this).find('.page').position().left
    }, 1000);
});
```

This works fine on the first click but the second click doesn't work. Subsequent clicks do work but not every time.

I think because it's trying to scroll to a particular value, it is not getting the correct value perhaps.

Is it possible to just smooth scroll to a given element rather than its positional value?

Comment: Also, if you ever need a jQuery method like `scrollTo`, there is an unofficial plugin for that: http://flesler.blogspot.ro/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working like this in the end:

```
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollLeft: $(this).scrollLeft() + $(this).find('.page').position().left
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always going to scroll to the first `.page` element.

Try:

```
var i = 0;
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollLeft: $(this).find('.page').eq(i).position().left
    }, 1000);
    i++;
});
```

Basically every click the `i` variable gets incremented and every click we are searching for the `i'th` `.page`.

Comment: Have you tried it? I would say it is not possible to use `scrollLeft` or `scrollTop` if the div has `overflow:hidden`...